# My E-Commerce website shows all products plus filters but individual item page does not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

My "show all" page works which depicts all my products on one page and even filters by category. Once you click on that item it should take you to the "individual item" page but it does not work and im not sure why. Here is both those files. File 1 has no issues showing all the products with the names and images. Once you click the link it takes you to a blank screen with the link such as http://localhost:3000/product/7

Products page

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addCart } from "../redux/action";

import "react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import data from "./data.json";

const Products = () => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(data);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const addProduct = (product) => {
    dispatch(addCart(product));
  };

  const filterProduct = (cat) => {
    const updatedList = data.filter((item) => item.category === cat);
    setFilter(updatedList);
  };
  const ShowProducts = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="buttons text-center py-5">
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-2"
            onClick={() => setFilter(data)}
          >
            All
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-2"
            onClick={() => filterProduct("martial arts")}
          >
            Martial Art's
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-2"
            onClick={() => filterProduct("equipment")}
          >
            Equipment
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-2"
            onClick={() => filterProduct("outdoor")}
          >
            Outdoor
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-2"
            onClick={() => filterProduct("other")}
          >
            Other
          </button>
        </div>

        {filter.map((product) => {
          return (
            <div
              id={product.id}
              key={product.id}
              className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-12 mb-4"
            >
              <div
                className="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded text-center h-100"
                key={product.id}
              >
                <Link to={"/product/" + product.id}>
                  <div className="box w-content">
                    <img
                      className="card-img-top p-3"
                      src={product.image}
                      alt="Card"
                      height={300}
                    />
                    <div className="frame"></div>
                  </div>
                </Link>

                <div className="card-body">
                  <Link to={"/product/" + product.id}>
                    <h5 className="card-title">
                      {product.title.substring(0, 20)}...
                    </h5>
                    <p className="card-text">
                      {product.description.substring(0, 90)}...
                    </p>
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                  <li className="list-group-item lead">$ {product.price}</li>
                  {/* <li className="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li className="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li> */}
                </ul>
                <div className="card-body">
                  {/* <Link to={"/product/" + product.id} className="btn btn-dark m-1">
                        Buy Now
                      </Link> */}
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-dark m-1"
                    onClick={() => addProduct(product)}
                  >
                    Add to Cart
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container my-3 py-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <h2 className="display-5 text-center">Latest Products</h2>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row justify-content-center">{<ShowProducts />}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Product detail page

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Marquee from "react-fast-marquee";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addCart } from "../redux/action";
import data from "../components/data.json";
import { Footer, Navbar } from "../components";

const Product = () => {
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState({});
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [similarProducts, setSimilarProducts] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(id);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProductData(productData);
    const productData = data.filter((item) => item.id === id);
    if (productData.length > 0) {
      setProduct(productData[0]);
      const similarData = data.filter(
        (item) => item.category === productData[0].category
      );
      setSimilarProducts(similarData);
    }
  }, []);

  const addProduct = (product) => {
    dispatch(addCart(product));
  };

  const ShowProduct = () => {
    console.log(product);
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container my-5 py-2">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 py-3">
              <img
                className="img-fluid"
                src={product.image}
                alt={product.title}
                width="400px"
                height="400px"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-6 py-5">
              <h4 className="text-uppercase text-muted">{product.category}</h4>
              <h1 className="display-5">{product.title}</h1>
              <h3 className="display-6  my-4">${product.price}</h3>
              <p className="lead">{product.description}</p>
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-dark"
                onClick={() => addProduct(product)}
              >
                Add to Cart
              </button>
              <Link to="/cart" className="btn btn-dark mx-3">
                Go to Cart
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

  const ShowSimilarProduct = () => {
    console.log(similarProducts);
    return (
      <>
        <div className="py-4 my-4">
          <div className="d-flex">
            {similarProducts.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div key={item.id} className="card mx-4 text-center">
                  <img
                    className="card-img-top p-3"
                    src={item.image}
                    alt="Card"
                    height={300}
                    width={300}
                  />
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">
                      {item.title.substring(0, 15)}...
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <Link
                      to={"/product/" + item.id}
                      className="btn btn-dark m-1"
                    >
                      Buy Now
                    </Link>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-dark m-1"
                      onClick={() => addProduct(item)}
                    >
                      Add to Cart
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {<ShowProduct />}
          <div className="row my-5 py-5">
            <div className="d-none d-md-block">
              <h2 className="">You may also Like</h2>
              <Marquee pauseOnHover={true} pauseOnClick={true} speed={50}>
                {<ShowSimilarProduct />}
              </Marquee>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

The error:

```js
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'productData' before initialization
        at Product.jsx:19:1
        at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
        at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
        at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
        at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
        at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
        at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
        at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
        at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
        at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    (anonymous) @ Product.jsx:19
    commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
    commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
    commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
    commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
    commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
    flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
    flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
    workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
    react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Product> component:
    
        at Product (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5597:88)
        at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:57894:5)
        at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58343:5)
        at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53627:5)
        at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58274:15)
        at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56495:5)
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
    logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
    update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
    commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
    commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
    commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
    commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
    commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
    commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
    commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
    performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
    flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
    flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27060
    flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
    workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
    Product.jsx:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'productData' before initialization
        at Product.jsx:19:1
        at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
        at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
        at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
        at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
        at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
        at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
        at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
        at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
        at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
```

Comment: I see a couple of console.log running in page 2. Any detailed output on that? Developer Console. ${product.price} looks inconsistent (might not be the root cause, just stumbled over it)

Comment: @ChristianUnnerstall I just updated this post to show the console log statements

Comment: You have a `productData` state and in your `useEffect` you're setting that again, seems odd? Also you create a new variable with the same name as the `productData` state, might be something there. And a hint: you can use the `find` method on `data` to get one product instead of using `filter` :)

Comment: @RubenSmn It finally works now! That was what I needed thank you!!

Comment: In regards to the error output. Remove the first line in useEffect "setProductData(productData)".